# Angular 2: Error: No provider for Http! (AccountService -> Http)

Tags: angular

My `main.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http'
import { ClientDashboardTwoAppComponent, environment } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(ClientDashboardTwoAppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

I tried adding the http service into my service because I am just hardcoding the response of `all()` right now:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {} // <------------------ just added and it broke my tests

  all() {
    return Promise.resolve([
      { name: "Account 1" },
      { name: "Account 2" },
      { name: "Account 3" },
    ]);
  }

}
```

However, that line breaks the tests of the component using this service (fyi these specs came from the angular cli generator, all I did was add the `AccountService` provider in `beforeEachProviders()`):

```
import {
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder } from '@angular/compiler/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EngagementTableComponent } from './engagement-table.component';
import { AccountService } from '../account.service';

describe('Component: EngagementTable', () => {
  let builder: TestComponentBuilder;

  beforeEachProviders(() => [EngagementTableComponent, AccountService]);
  beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], function (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) {
    builder = tcb;
  }));

  it('should inject the component', inject([EngagementTableComponent],
      (component: EngagementTableComponent) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should create the component', inject([], () => {
    return builder.createAsync(EngagementTableComponentTestController)
      .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
        let query = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(EngagementTableComponent));
        expect(query).toBeTruthy();
        expect(query.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
      });
  }));
});

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
    <engagement-table></engagement-table>
  `,
  directives: [EngagementTableComponent]
})
class EngagementTableComponentTestController {
}
```

Am I missing a step? Do I have to inject something into the specs?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure  `package.json` has `@angular/http` package added to load `Http` dependency module correctly.

```
"dependencies": {
    ....,
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1", //<--add it in package.json
    ....,
    ....
}
```

Comment: yeh it's there. when i remove `constructor(private http: Http) {}` it doesn't break anymore

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: yep i am. does that make anything different

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, injecting http is breaking something. I came across this in making a plunker to illustrate another issue - I can't even get that far now. Here is plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/116GhDn4vt0uKBz65alB?p=preview

Comment: the issue in plunkr seems to be very different.. its not related to Http

Comment: Plunker issue solved: started w/ new template that uses rc.2. https://plnkr.co/edit/AW1nD7ixY27YzDRRwOgT?p=preview